# Ошибка компеляции setType в Vk api

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Пишу бота на Java с vk api.
Сам код:

```
    TransportClient transportClient = new HttpTransportClient();
    VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);
    Random random = new Random();
    Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();

    List<List<KeyboardButton>> allKey = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Keyboard> line1 = new ArrayList<>();
    line1.add(new KeyboardButton().setAction(new KeyboardButtonAction().setLabel("Привет").setType(KeyboardButtonActionType.TEXT)).setColor(KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE));
    line1.add(new KeyboardButton().setAction(new KeyboardButtonAction().setLabel("Кто я?").setType(KeyboardButtonActionType.TEXT)).setColor(KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE));
    allKey.add(line1);
    keyboard.setButtons(allKey);
    GroupActor actor = new GroupActor(211045078, "Key");
    Integer ts = vk.messages().getLongPollServer(actor).execute().getTs();
    while(true){
        MessagesGetLongPollHistoryQuery historyQuery = vk.messages().getLongPollHistory(actor).ts(ts);
        List<Message> messages = historyQuery.execute().getMessages().getItems();
        if(!messages.isEmpty()){
            messages.forEach(message -> {
                System.out.println(message.toString());

                try {
                    if (message.getText().equals("Привет")){
                        vk.messages().send(actor).message("Привет").userId(message.getFromId()).randomId(random.nextInt(10000)).execute();
                    }
                    else if (message.getText().equals("Кто я?")) {
                        vk.messages().send(actor).message("Ты хороший человек.").userId(message.getFromId()).randomId(random.nextInt(10000)).execute();
                    }
                    else if (message.getText().equals("Кнопки")){
                        vk.messages().send(actor).message("А вот и они").userId(message.getFromId()).randomId(random.nextInt(10000)).keyboard(keyboard).execute();
                    }

                    else {
                        vk.messages().send(actor).message("Я тебя не понял").userId(message.getFromId()).randomId(random.nextInt(10000)).execute();
                    }
                }catch (ApiException | ClientException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            });
        }
        ts = vk.messages().getLongPollServer(actor).execute().getTs();
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

}
Ошибку выдаёт такую
 `'setType(com.vk.api.sdk.objects.messages.TemplateActionTypeNames)' in 'com.vk.api.sdk.objects.messages.KeyboardButtonAction' cannot be applied to '(com.vk.api.sdk.objects.messages.KeyboardButtonActionType)'`

Comment: ну так, разные типы, что же хотите?

Comment: Угу. Просто руководство от vk полная идиотия. Я запутался пока читал этот Сизифов "труд".
Пришёл к это ошибке и просто умер:| . ДУмал может кто сталкивался с это проблемой

Comment: просто никому оно не нужно. Если бы хотя бы сам сайт vk работал - а то лежит постоянно...

Comment: Хорошо подмечено, мне просто дали задание на бота в вк,. И тут такой казус

Answer (score 0):

Так вам же программа разработки и говорит, в чём именно проблема - неправильный тип данных используете. Если вам не указывает на ошибку сразу, а только после попытки сборки - скачайте нормальную IDE, например `IntelliJ IDEA` от `JetBrains`, версия `Community` у них абсолютно бесплатная.

Теперь по ошибкам:

1. Лист `line1` у вас почему-то имеет тип `Keyboard`, хотя вы пытаетесь добавить туда `KeyboardButton`.
2. `setType` у `KeyboardButtonAction` имеет тип `TemplateActionTypeNames`, как и было указано в ошибке.

Тест работы приложения с этой частью кода: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WVUe.png

```
List<KeyboardButton> line1 = new ArrayList<>();
line1.add(
    new KeyboardButton()
        .setAction(
            new KeyboardButtonAction()
                .setLabel("Привет")
                .setType(TemplateActionTypeNames.TEXT)
        )
        .setColor(KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
);
```